Generic representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$
Let $F$ be a local field of characteristic $0$, $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$.
When $F$ is $p$-adic, Bernstein and Zelevinsky classified the irreducible generic representations. The statement is:

Let $\delta_{\Delta}$ be the generalized Steinberg representation associated to the segment $\Delta=[\rho\nu^{-\frac{k-1}{2}},\rho\nu^{\frac{k-1}{2}}]$, i.e. the unique irreducible subrepresentation of the parabolic induction
$$\rho\nu^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\times \cdots\times \rho\nu^{-\frac{k-1}{2}}:=I_{P}^G(\rho\nu^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\boxtimes \cdots\boxtimes \rho\nu^{-\frac{k-1}{2}}),$$
where $\rho$ is an irreducible supercuspidal of $\mathrm{GL}_m(F)$, $\nu=|\det_m|_F$ and $n=mk$. This classifies, up to a twist of central character, the essentially square integrable irreducible representations ("discrete series").

A generic irreducible smooth representation $\pi$ is of the form
$$\delta_{\Delta_1}\times \cdots \times \delta_{\Delta_r},$$
where no two intervals $\Delta_i,\Delta_j$ are linked (i.e. no inclusion relation, and the union is also a segment). Conversely, each such representation is generic, and in particular irreducible.


This gives a satsifactory answer to the $p$-adic case. For $F=\mathbb{R}$, I found that on Cogdell's lectures (Lectures on L-functions, converse theorems, and functoriality for $\mathrm{GL}_n$, Fields Institute Monograph, pp. 60) there is also a similar statement:

Statement: if $\pi$ is an irreducible admissible representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, then
$$\pi=I_P^G(\tau_1\boxtimes\cdots \boxtimes \tau_r),$$
and each $\tau_i$ is a twisted discrete series of $\mathrm{GL}_{n_i}(\mathbb{R})$ for $n_i\in \{1,2\}$ (since only $\mathrm{GL}_{1}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ have discrete series now).

I tried to find a source for this statement, which Cogdell said "is a result due to Vogan".
Jacquet-Shalika's famous Euler 1 paper has a related result, but not exactly what I am asking. Their result reads:

(Lemma 3.13) If $\pi$ is a unitary generic irreducible representation of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, then there exists a partition $\alpha=(n_1,\cdots,n_r)$ of $n$ with $n_i\in \{1,2,4\}$, and $\pi_i$ a unitary irreducible representation of $\mathrm{GL}_{n_i}(\mathbb{R})$, such that
$$\pi=I_{P_\alpha}^G(\pi_1\boxtimes \cdots\boxtimes \pi_r).$$
Moreover, each $\pi_i$ is generic.

It seems that this result is restricted to the unitary case, and is slightly different to the above statement, where Jacquet-Shalika used $1,2,4$ rather than $1,2$.
My questions:
(1) is there a source for the statement? It looks reasonable that the converse also holds, is this correct? (i.e. If $\pi=I_P^G(\tau_1\boxtimes\cdots\boxtimes\tau_r)$ is irreducible, each $\tau_i$ a twisted discrete series, then $\pi$ is generic.)
(2) why did Jacquet-Shalika used $1,2,4$ rather than $1,2$ in their statement? (similarly for $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ they used $1,2$.) It seems that this is not the same as Cogdell's statement (which looks more reasonable).
(3) how about the reducibility of $\pi=I_P^G(\tau_1\boxtimes\cdots\boxtimes\tau_r)$? (Also, for $p$-adic $F$, do we have $\delta_{\Delta_1}\times \cdots \times \delta_{\Delta_r}$ is reducible if and only if two $\Delta_i,\Delta_j$ are linked?)
[ (4) I also want to ask whether we can give an explicit list of the Langlands parameters for the unitary dual of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ classified by Vogan. But this is not really related to the title here.]
I guess these are very well-known for experts, but I am just a beginner.
Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

I think the relevant result of Vogan is contained in his paper "Gelfand-Kiriliov Dimension for Harish-Chandra Modules", Theorem 6.2, which classifies large (=generic) representations.
